# How to check that mysql connection is valid

Tags: node.js, mysql2

I'm using node, with 'mysql2' module, how can I check that the config settings are correct and connecting to the database correctly?

These are my connection settings, however I want to check that the database connection is valid before any queries are done, such as allowing the user to login.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const conn = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'hostname',
    port: port,
    database: 'db',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    dateStrings: 'date'
});

const pool = conn.promise();

module.exports = pool;
```

I added this code (before the module.exports line) to throw an error, but is there a better way of doing this? The error code -3008 relates to the 'ENOTFOUND' code, which is what I receive when the host name was incorrect and the connection failed.

```
pool.execute('SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1')
.catch(err => {
    if (err.errno === -3008) {
        throw new Error('Can\'t connect to database please check connection settings.');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

are you able to connect via command line in your mysql?

`mysql -h localhost -u myname -ppassword mydb`

Also, to test the connection before execute the query, I suggest you to use `.getConnection`